# Network printer doesn't print using IIS 7.5, but it prints when I run application in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, printing

I tried everything I could find on the Internet, but cannot print on Network Printer from IIS.
This is part of code:

```
rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = @"\\server\printer";
                rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

I added the printer as local printer on the IIS server. Added iusr, system and network users to the printer's user names.
I even configured registry and machine.config - to allow the System account to print.
I also use `<authentication mode="Forms">` so putting `<identity impersonate="true" userName="user" password="pass"/>` doesn't work.
I'm frustrated, as it works and prints when I run it from VS 2012.

Any help? Please.